# Iterating through a model in magento

Tags: magento

I am having trouble getting the following function to work:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order');
```

I attempted this, however it returned no results:

```
$res=Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$orderId=$res->getOrderId();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($orderId);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Order Increment Id in Magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195743/get-order-increment-id-in-magento)

Comment: Are you trying to find the order ids of all orders on your Magento install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess by `res` you mean resource so I'll make a leap of logic and assume you mean to query a *resource collection*.

```
echo '<pre>';
$resource = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
foreach ($resource as $order) {
    echo $order->getId(), "\n";
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$itemcount=count($items);
$name=array();
$unitPrice=array();
$sku=array();
$ids=array();
$qty=array();
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
 $name[] = $item->getName();
 $unitPrice[]=$item->getPrice();
 $sku[]=$item->getSku();
 $ids[]=$item->getProductId();
 $qty[]=$item->getQtyToInvoice();
}
```

Comment: i dont have $order_id.then how can i move further.Please tell me another way or please tell me how can i find $order_id