# How to pull customer email on Magento Checkout Success.phtml 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've tried various solutions online to no avail.  I think it should be something like:

```
<?php
$order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
?>

An email confirmation was sent to: <?php echo $order->getEmail ?>
```

I am able to display order ID with:

```
<?php echo $this->getOrderId() ?>
```

If you have a suggestion, please be as specific as you can because I am definitely a novice.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this to Success.phtml

```
<?php
   $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
   echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
?>
```

Read more: [Get Order Increment ID in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195743/get-order-increment-id-in-magento)

Comment: I had tried that thread.  Perhaps I am not displaying the variable properly:  <?php echo $email ?>

Comment: Try my new code above... I was loading the order by order id but the id that it display on the success page is the order increment id

Comment: This worked!  I placed the second line in the file where I needed it and the email address was populated.  Thank you.

Comment: Could you mark my above answer as the solution...so everyone will know that it is solve and not spend time tying to solve it. ty

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
$_customerId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();

$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();

$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 

$order->load($lastOrderId);
```

Then do

```
foreach($order as $_order){
    echo $_order->getCustomerEmail();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Something about this halts the code from executing.  It could be my implementing the last line in the form: <?php foreach($order as $_order){echo $_order->getCustomerEmail();} ?>

Comment: The above code will not work because when you use ->load() it will return 1 record/object (one record per id) so you cannot using foreach loop when it not array of object