# Magento success.phtml adding tracking code for affiliate

Tags: magento, tracking, affiliate

Have a slight problem getting the order data in success.phtml to load in Magento 1.7.0.2. I need to have the data inserted into a tracking code so I can send it to the affiliate. As always, way behind schedule with this one.

Data Needed:
Order Id:
Customer Id: (if loggedin)
Order Amount: (Subtotal - Discount, if any)
Number of items Ordered:
Currency of Order Amount:
And the Customers name:

Thanks to lots of help available across the web, I've come up with the following:

```
    <?php $total=0;
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($this->getOrderId());
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    $items = $order->getAllItems();
    $amount = number_format($order->getSubtotal() + $order->getDiscountAmount(),2);
    $custname = $order->getCustomerName();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $total = $total + $qty;
    } 
    ?>

    <img src='https://www.tagserve.asia/saleServlet?MID=XX&PID=XX&CRID=<?php echo $customer; ?>&ORDERID=<?php echo $this->getOrderId(); ?>&ORDERAMNT=<?php echo $amount; ?>&NUMOFITEMS=<?php echo $total; ?>&CUR=<?php echo $order->getOrderCurrencyCode(); ?>&SUBID=<?php echo $custname; ?>' border='0' width='1' height='1'>
```

It's seems that the orderid is a no brainer, but the $amount just shows up as 0.00, the currency code is non existent and through lots of trial and error the number of items in the order still aludes me.

This needs to be backwards compatible with 1.4 so I'm hoping there is someone who can help me piece it together.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195743/get-order-increment-id-in-magento

Comment: Also to make it easier to debug success.phtml you can use this trick http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/835/how-to-test-or-style-the-order-success-page

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getData());
```

From the above generated list get all the necessary information.

for debugging purpose you should

```
//comment below line
 $session->clear();
//from successAction of OnepageController
```

this will prevent you from placeing the order again and again,