# How to get the next order id of orders in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have been using below code to get the next order id in Magento

```
     $getNewOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);
```

This works fine but the problem for this code is it changes the **increment_last_id** field in table **eav_entity_store** to this new order id.

So, if your order was not processed, the order id has already incremented and hence the order id would get lost, as next time before creating orders Magento will increment this value in the table and process the order.

How can we get the next order id without incrementing the value in the table, it obviously will change the value in this table when the order is created in the latter part of the code.

*I am using this piece of code to create orders programmatically*

Comment: have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195743/get-order-increment-id-in-magento

Comment: Tx I did, but it did not work in my case. I am programmatically entering some orders using custom codes and the solution in the link is for checkout page orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$entityStoreConfig = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_store')->loadByEntityStore($this->getId(), $storeId);

$incrementInstance = Mage::getModel($this->getIncrementModel())
            ->setPrefix($entityStoreConfig->getIncrementPrefix())
            ->setPadLength($this->getIncrementPadLength())
            ->setPadChar($this->getIncrementPadChar())
            ->setLastId($entityStoreConfig->getIncrementLastId())
            ->setEntityTypeId($entityStoreConfig->getEntityTypeId())
            ->setStoreId($entityStoreConfig->getStoreId());

$nextId = $incrementInstance->getNextId();
```

The code is taken from the `fetchNewIncrementId` method. I just omitted the save part.

Comment: Thanks for the tip will dig deeper.

Comment: @Pradino. You don't need to dig deeper. That's the exact code you need. Wrap it up in a method inside a helper or a model and use it.

Comment: Yes just did that. I had to add something and its all done.
`Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('order');` to get some values.